# How to print date without time in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, raw-query-builder

The following query is giving me time with date but i need only date .How do I do?

```
$data = DB::table('kahanighar_ivr.kahani_cdr')
                ->select(DB::raw('count(*) as a'),'dst','calldate as ibdate',DB::raw('"kahani" as ser'))
                ->where('dst','like','%7787%')
                ->wheredate('calldate','>=',"$request->start")
                ->wheredate('calldate','<=',"$request->end")
                ->groupBy('dst')->groupBy('calldate')
                ->union(DB::table('kids_ivr.kids_cdr')
                    ->select(DB::raw('count(*) as a'),'dst','calldate as ibdate',DB::raw('"kids" as ser'))
                    ->where('dst','like','%7787%')
                    ->wheredate('calldate','>=',"$request->start")
                    ->wheredate('calldate','<=',"$request->end")
                    ->groupBy('dst')->groupBy('calldate'))
                ->union(DB::table('news_ivr.news_cdr')
                    ->select(DB::raw('count(*) as a'),'dst','calldate as ibdate',DB::raw('"news" as ser'))
                    ->where('dst','like','%7787%')
                    ->wheredate('calldate','>=',"$request->start")
                    ->wheredate('calldate','<=',"$request->end")
                    ->groupBy('dst')->groupBy('calldate'));
```

Comment: Wherever you print the time and date, just format to fit your needs. Example: `\Carbon\Carbon::parse($data->calldate)->format('d.m.Y')`. Or actually I might misunderstand your question.

Comment: Perhaps `'DATE(calldate) as ibdate'` instead of `'calldate as ibdate'`?

Comment: when i do as 'calldate as ibdate' i get error of undefined calldate column

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? If this is really about printing (like given in the title of your question), please share more details. The currently shared code does not print anything

Answer (score 0):

Put `->get()` at the end of the query to get the data

```
 $data = DB::table('kahanighar_ivr.kahani_cdr')
                ->select(DB::raw('count(*) as a'),'dst','calldate as ibdate',DB::raw('"kahani" as ser'))
                ->where('dst','like','%7787%')
                ->wheredate('calldate','>=',"$request->start")
                ->wheredate('calldate','<=',"$request->end")
                ->groupBy('dst')->groupBy('calldate')
                ->union(DB::table('kids_ivr.kids_cdr')
                    ->select(DB::raw('count(*) as a'),'dst','calldate as ibdate',DB::raw('"kids" as ser'))
                    ->where('dst','like','%7787%')
                    ->wheredate('calldate','>=',"$request->start")
                    ->wheredate('calldate','<=',"$request->end")
                    ->groupBy('dst')->groupBy('calldate'))
                ->union(DB::table('news_ivr.news_cdr')
                    ->select(DB::raw('count(*) as a'),'dst','calldate as ibdate',DB::raw('"news" as ser'))
                    ->where('dst','like','%7787%')
                    ->wheredate('calldate','>=',"$request->start")
                    ->wheredate('calldate','<=',"$request->end")
                    ->groupBy('dst')->groupBy('calldate'))->get();
```

Then use foreach loop to iterate the data

```
foreach($data as $item)
{
    echo \Carbon\Carbon::parse($item->calldate)->format('d.m.Y');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use [mysql](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_date.asp) DATE function, it Extract the date part

```
$data = DB::table('kahanighar_ivr.kahani_cdr')
                ->select(DB::raw('count(*) as a'),'dst',DB::raw('Date(calldate) as ibdate',DB::raw('"kahani" as ser'))
                ->where('dst','like','%7787%')
                ->wheredate('calldate','>=',"$request->start")
                ->wheredate('calldate','<=',"$request->end")
                ->groupBy('dst')->groupBy('calldate')
                ->union(DB::table('kids_ivr.kids_cdr')
                    ->select(DB::raw('count(*) as a'),'dst','calldate as ibdate',DB::raw('"kids" as ser'))
                    ->where('dst','like','%7787%')
                    ->wheredate('calldate','>=',"$request->start")
                    ->wheredate('calldate','<=',"$request->end")
                    ->groupBy('dst')->groupBy('calldate'))
                ->union(DB::table('news_ivr.news_cdr')
                    ->select(DB::raw('count(*) as a'),'dst','calldate as ibdate',DB::raw('"news" as ser'))
                    ->where('dst','like','%7787%')
                    ->wheredate('calldate','>=',"$request->start")
                    ->wheredate('calldate','<=',"$request->end")
                    ->groupBy('dst')->groupBy('calldate'))->get();
```